# How can I increment a sequence by more than 1 in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

What's the best way to atomically update a sequence in Postgres?

Context: I'm bulk inserting objects with SQLAlchemy, and `exectutemany` can't return defaults, so I'd like to increment the primary key sequence by the amount of objects I need to insert.

I know I can do:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE seq INCREMENT BY 1000;
```

But I'm not sure if that's safe to do in concurrent environments.

Comment: ALTER SEQUENCE will not immediately affect nextval results in backends, other than the current one, that have preallocated (cached) sequence values. They will use up all cached values prior to noticing the changed sequence generation parameters. The current backend will be affected immediately.

ALTER SEQUENCE does not affect the currval status for the sequence. (Before PostgreSQL 8.3, it sometimes did.)

ALTER SEQUENCE blocks concurrent nextval, currval, lastval, and setval calls.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-altersequence.html

It blocks others but is safe to do.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `setval()` combined with `nextval()`

```
select setval('my_sequence', nextval('my_sequence') + 999);
```

This *increments* the current value by 1000, it does not set it to a fixed value.

Answer (score 2):

As Laurenz Albe suggests: I called `nextval` 1000 times.

```
SELECT nextval('common_id_seq') FROM generate_series(1, 1000);
```

The advantage to this over a a_horse_with_no_name's suggestion is that I don't need to grant `setval` privileges to the user.

Comment: this also gives back the 1000 values from the sequence. if you have a highly concurrent system, is it possible that another `nextval()` could be called in the middle of the `generate_series` execution, resulting in the values not being perfectly sequential? (i'm guessing it is possible, so if you're trying to say give IDs to 1000 items, this is the safest way to do it)

Comment: That's actually a really good point.  It might mean that the `common_id` mightn't match the order of creation, which could be an issue for a fault tolerant system that depends on this.

It might make sense to put this behind some kind of lock

Answer (score 1):

That would be safe, since `ALTER SEQUENCE` takes an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the sequence.

There are two problems:

- this will block all concurrent usage of the sequence until your transaction is completed
- you don't know the starting value

You could work around the second problem like this:

```
BEGIN;
ALTER SEQUENCE seq INCREMENT BY 1000;
SELECT nextval('seq');
COMMIT;
```

Then you know that that value and the preceding 999 ondes are yours.

But I think the best way is to call `nextval` 1000 times.